# html/javascript automaticly getting link from submit button (maybe automating with python?)

Tags: javascript, python, html, webforms, automation

I have a website where I have to click a submit button on a form. This gives me a link. I know the link is made up with the paramter that is passed through a hidden value. I was wondering if I could make a python script or something else that would go to the website and click some buttons returning the link that the submit button generates, if so how could I pass the extra parameter that influences the creation of the link?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is python you're looking for then give the [Mechanize](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize/0.1.11) library a shot. If you are just extracting small but unique elements of the HTML document then you may as well use regex's with python. To work with the HTML document more pragmatically then [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) may be more beneficial, which you can combine with mechanize/python.

It's more straightforward than it may initially seem.

Comment: I have look at mechanize but I'm wondering if it would work. because the website checks if the page has loaded 3 jpegs(advertising). Can this also be emulated with mechanize?

Comment: If it's a javascript check, then yes you can use the spidermonkey javascript engine with mechanize:  http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-spidermonkey

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this documentation](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/urllib2.shtml#data) of the `urlib2` package.  Below is the code you would use, but the documentation explains (very well) what is happening.

Excerpt:

```
import urllib
import urllib2

url = 'http://www.someserver.com/cgi-bin/register.cgi'
values = {'name' : 'Michael Foord',
          'location' : 'Northampton',
          'language' : 'Python' }

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
```

You would need to use an HTML parser like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to obtain the parameter name and value that is being posted when you click the button.

**Edit:**

Yes, you could use [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) for this as well.  You would do something like this (untested):

```
from mechanize import Browser

br = Browser()
br.open("http://www.example.com/")  # this would be your website
br.select_form(name="order")        # change this to the name of your form
response = br.submit()              # submits the form, just like if you clicked the submit button
print response.geturl()             # prints the URL you are looking for
```

You'll need to make this specific to your website/form, but something along these lines should do the trick.

Check out the [examples/documentation](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/ClientForm/) for the `ClientForm` object if you find you need more control.

Comment: I've used urllib2 before but I think mechanize will be more of a solution because of the javascript that happens on the page. correct me if I'm wrong...

Comment: will mechanize also pass all the coockies and such? if so then this is the perfect solution for me !:)

Comment: The basic `mechanize.urlopen` function handles cookies automatically, but I couldn't get to the documentation for the Browser object to see if it does as well. Some more useful documentation: http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/doc.html

Comment: I took a look at the source for the `Browser` object and the comments indicate the "cookie handling is [...] entirely automatic".

Comment: thank alot!. I wish I could somehow vote on you but I don't have any reputation :(.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have downloaded your html data with [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/doc.html) as other users said, then you could use [Beautifulsoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Parsing%20HTML) like this:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_data)
hidden_tag = soup.find('input',name='hiddenId',type='hidden') 
hidden_value = hiddenId['value']
```

then you could forge a POST with urllib2 like this:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
url = 'http://yoursite.com'
values = {'yourhiddenname' : hidden_value}
request = urllib2.Request(url, urllib.urlencode(values))
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
result = response.read()
```